# Why does my state affect the emitted events from a click handler?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have (what seems to be) a very peculiar situation where I seem to be getting extra events emitted based on my Redux state.

I have narrowed the behavior down to whether or not I make a *successful* request to my `/users` endpoint and retrieve a list of users which is then stored in Redux.

*If* the commented code is **not** active (as it is currently shown), I am able to successfully render the modal(s) reliably *and* step between states.

[image]

*If* the commented code is active, the  (which is what is behind the  as well) emits an `onDismiss` call immediately. This has the result of *closing* the  modal immediately.

[image]

*If* the commented code is active, **but** the response from the thunk is a 401 and the user data is **not** loaded (i.e., the state of the `user` key in `redux` is a failure, not success, then the modal *works* -- though of course, there are no users to select.

I have confirmed this behavior is consistent no matter *where* I seem to make this fetch request (initially it was in the `App.tsx` to be called immediately. I also tried it in an intermediate component).

Question(s):

1. Can you explain *why* I might be getting different behavior in my click handlers based on what is in my state?
2. Is there something I'm missing and I'm conflating my Redux state with the actual behavior?
3. I *know* I can solve this by adding a `event.stopPropagation()` call in strategic places (e.g., on the first button that opens the `<ConfirmationBox>` and then again on the button in the `<ConfirmationBox>` that transitions to the `SelectUser` modal), but are there *other* solutions?

```
//pinFlow.tsx
type States =
  | { state: 'Confirm' }
  | { state: 'SelectUser' }
  | { state: 'SubmitPin'; user: User };

export function pinFlow<T extends ConfirmationBoxProps>(
  ConfirmationBox: React.FC<T>,
  authorization: Authorization,
) {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState<States>({ state: 'Confirm' });

    // const dispatch=useDispatch();
    // initialize users
    // const users = useSelector((state: InitialState) => state.pinAuth.users);
    // const fetchUsers = useCallback(() => {
    //   dispatch(fetchUsersThunk());
    // }, [dispatch]);
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   if (users.state === RemoteDataState.NotStarted) {
    //     fetchUsers();
    //   }
    // }, [fetchUsers, users.state]);

    return (props: T) => {
      const users = useSelector((state: InitialState) =>
        mapRemoteData(state.pinAuth.users, users =>
          users.filter(user => user.authorizations.includes(authorization)),
        ),
      );

      switch (state.state) {
        case 'Confirm': {
          return (
            <ConfirmationBox
              {...props}
              onSubmit={(_event: React.MouseEvent) => {
                setState({ state: 'SelectUser' });
              }}
            />
          );
        }
        case 'SelectUser': {
          return (
            <Modal
              title={'PIN Required'}
              canClickOutsideToDismiss={true}
              onDismiss={() => {
                setState({ state: 'Confirm' });
              }}
            >
              <p className={style.selectProfileText}>Select your profile:</p>
              <pre>
                <code>{JSON.stringify(users, null, 4)}</code>
              </pre>
              {/*
              <UserList users={users.data} /> */}
            </Modal>
          );
        }
        default: {
          return <Modal title="others">all others</Modal>;
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

The code is used in another component like so:

```
function Comp(){

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  const [mode, setMode] = useState();

  const ConfirmationModal =
    protected
      ? pinFlow(MenuItemModal, permission)
      : MenuItemModal;

  return(
    <ConfirmationModal
      item={selected}
      mode={mode}
      disabled={availability.state === RemoteDataState.Loading}
      errorMessage={tryGetError(availability)}
      onCancel={() => {
        setMode(undefined);
        dispatch(resetAvailability());
      }}
      onSubmit={(accessToken: string) => {
        dispatch(findAction(selected, mode, accessToken));
      }}
    />
  )

}
```

Comment: I wonder if you `const confirmationModal = useMemo(() => protected ? pinflow(MenuItemModal, permission) : MenuItemModal, [protected]);` it will behave how you expect

Comment: @shamsup - I like the idea, but you can't actually do that since `pinFlow` has its own hooks - and calling hooks w/in hooks violates the rules of hooks.